# Excel: How to SUM without duplicating data in a filtered table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this table that refers to subway stations and surrounding population, I need to sum the population without duplicating even when data is filtered.

[image]

Subtotal gives me 74,536 when in reality, we are talking about 46,601 individuals. Now, the problem I have is when data is filtered by stations

[image]

It keeps showing 46,601 when thats not the case. How can I solve this?

FYI, the formula I´m using in Col B:`=SUMPRODUCT([Col B]/COUNTIF([Col B],[Col B]))`

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @bigben, subtotal will sum everything, even if areas are duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a **array** formula:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET([ColB],ROW([ColB])-ROW(B2),,1)),[ColB]),[ColB]),[ColB]))
```

Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar

[image]

I suggest using the Formula Evaluator tool to understand how this works.

The `SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET...` returns an array of `{1;1;1;0;0;0...}` where `1` represents a visible row.

We use that to return an array of the values in the visible rows.

The `FREQUENCY` function, where `data` and `bins` are the same will then return an array where the first of a duplicated value will return a count of that value, and the other instances will return a `0`.

We use that to return only the visible, non-duplicate instances and sum them.

Comment: This is it, it works perfectly! I´m still trying to understand it, first time using OFFSET and Arrays but with you breaking it down sure will be helpful. Thank you!